# x86_64 crashkernel=64M why?

Tags: linux-kernel, coredump, crash-dumps

I'm a newbie to kernel development and am trying to understand how the core dumps work. I came across the crashkernel memory size for various platforms like for eg: for x86_64 the recommended crashkernel size is said to be 64M and for the ppc64 it's 128M. How are these sizes determined?

Comment: Nohow, it just must be enough for simple into bash loading